# Gradle: Only Use Library from Dependency Manager when corresponding project dependency not available

Tags: gradle

to simplify the whole question, just asume that I have the following projects:

- my-commons
- my-application

"my-Application" has a dependency on "my-commons".
Both of them are always uploaded to Artifactory on commit by the CI-Server.

I have now two choices for "my-application" to get "my-commons"

1. Create a project dependency in gradle
2. Add a JAR dependency in gradle with groupid, artifactid and version

But what I want is a combination:
If the project "my-commons" is available under the expected location, use it as project dependency.
When the project isn't available, reference it as normal JAR dependency.

The reason for this is, that some of our developers just need one certain project and are not developing anything in the commons-layer (which has around 50). Others do a lot of refactoring work, and for them it's quite convenient to have all the projects in the workspace.

Thanks in advance
Guenther

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new feature in gradle 2.5 for [dependency substitution rules](https://docs.gradle.org/2.5/release-notes#dependency-substitution-rules) which you could apply based on whatever custom logic you like.

There's also [prezi pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride) which allows you to work with a group of projects (requires each project to be within it's own svn / git repo) by generating a dynamic multi-module gradle buildfile

** edit **

There's also a new [composite build support](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/exciting-new-buildship-features-coming-up/14728) feature coming soon to the [buildship](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) eclipse plugin which will resolve dependencies matching open projects in your eclipse workspace. It sounds very promising